# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyyaml>=5.3, but PyYAML is version 5.3.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, setup.py, pyyaml

I am using SetupTools to build a [package of my own](https://test.pypi.org/project/r3po/0.0.6/). In INSTALL_REQUIRES in `setup.py` I have the following dependencies:

```py
...
INSTALL_REQUIRES = [
    'ray>=0.8.7',
    'pyyaml>=5.3',
]

setup(name=PACKAGE_NAME,
      version=VERSION,
      description=DESCRIPTION,
      long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
      long_description_content_type=LONG_DESC_TYPE,
      author=AUTHOR,
      license=LICENSE,
      author_email=AUTHOR_EMAIL,
      url=URL,
      install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
      packages=find_packages()
      )
```

When I run `pip3 install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ r3po==0.0.6`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyyaml>=5.3 (from r3po==0.0.6) (from versions: 3.11)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyyaml>=5.3 (from r3po==0.0.6)
```

However, `pip3 search pyyaml` shows me that
PyYAML is definitely there:

`PyYAML (5.3.1) - YAML parser and emitter for Python`

and `pip3 install pyyaml` (in a `.venv` that has `pyyaml` installed) gives

`Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in /home/lieu/dev/inzura-clustering-project/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.3.1)`

And before you ask --- yes, I've tried all combinations of `PyYAML`, `pyyaml`, `5.3.1`, `5.3`, and so on, but nothing has worked.
I even tried to remove the version requirement (so `INSTALL_REQUIRES=['ray>=0.87','pyyaml']`) but this leads to another error:

```sh
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/lieu/dev/r3po/sample/.venv/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/pip-egg-info/PyYAML.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/pip-egg-info/PyYAML.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/pip-egg-info/PyYAML.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/pip-egg-info/PyYAML.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-w32z04mo/pyyaml/pip-egg-info/PyYAML.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    error: package directory 'lib3/yaml' does not exist
```

Comment: use `--extra-index-url`, people rarely upload packages to testpypi and `-i` will prevent pip from looking anywhere else

Comment: It also effects other packages such as `mysql-connector-python` from pypi. Even now with `--use-feature=2020-resolver` I also have this error on Amazon Linux 2 (centos) and the only way i can build the app is in a venv and directly run `python -m pip install pyyaml` with or without the version. It makes it an effort to onboard teams and deploy apps in more than 1 env ready for the app (like CI/CD build agents that are not meant to have persistent app specific deps). I really need a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anthony Sottile's suggestion to use `--extra-index-url` worked for me.